# Are the Cantor set and $B=\{\frac{1}{n}|n\in Z^+\}$ homeomorphic?

Tags: general-topology, cantor-set

Is the Cantor set homeomorphic to $B=\{\frac{1}{n}|n\in Z^+\}$? So far, I have concluded both sets are bounded and closed, therefore both are compact by the Heine-Borel Theorem. Neither are path connected or connected. Also, neither have the fixed-point property. So, I posit that they are homeomorphic. Now, assuming I am correct, I am supposed to construct an explicit homeomorphism between the two sets. How do I go about starting this part? And in general, how do I go about constructing explicit homeomorphisms from the Cantor set to another set? I have trouble grasping intuitively the Cantor set itself. Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: There is not even a bijection, setting continuity aside. As for intuition about the Cantor set, it is closed, bounded, has empty interior, and is "perfect" i.e. all of its points are limit points.

Comment: Why do you have to do it topologically? Any homeomorphism is a bijection and their cardinalities are already different.

Comment: Also, what makes you think $B$ is closed?

Comment: @coreyman317: $B$ is closed in itself, sure. Every set is closed in itself. But $B$ is not closed in $\mathbb{R}$, hence $B$ is not compact.

Comment: You will show they are not homeomorphic.  This means you need to first think of all the topological properties of the Cantor set that you know.  We cannot tell which properties you have learned, so we cannot do this step for you.  Second, you need to consider whether each of these properties is shared by $B$.  Since you incorrectly stated that $B$ is compact, it seems you have some review to do, also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$C$, the Cantor set, is uncountable, compact and has no isolated points (no $x \in C$ such that $\{x\}$ is open in $C$).

$B$ is countable, not closed (in $\mathbb{R}$) so not compact and all of its points are isolated points.

They hardly can be more different IMHO.